# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Linguistics breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0          9
Users destroyed                                   2          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            11        480
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                0        135
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue          6        344
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                0        200
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 2        856
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue                8      2,030
Tags merged                                       1          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             1          0
Tag synonyms created                              1          0
Questions reopened                                6          1
Questions protected                               0          7
Questions migrated                               17          0
Questions flagged⁴                                0        254
Questions closed                                 57        342
Question flags handled⁴                         154        100
Posts unlocked                                    0          5
Posts undeleted                                   2         16
Posts locked                                      0         29
Posts deleted⁵                                   84        540
Posts bumped                                      0        234
Escalations to the CM team                        1          0
Comments undeleted                                1          0
Comments flagged                                  0        228
Comments deleted⁶                               149        719
Comment flags handled                            95        133
Answers flagged                                   0        378
Answer flags handled                            253        125
All comments on a post moved to chat              2          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Only 2 edits reviews outside SO (and maybe a couple other big sites). I don't know if you're still posting this on any other sites, but if you have any to go, maybe you can fix it :)

Comment: Hey Shog9! Thanks for the data, and happy new year as well!